# Facebook login sometimes failing on WordPress site

Tags: wordpress, authentication, facebook-login

I am working on a site that is built in WordPress and facing one issue that as per the plugin when we logged in with Facebook to the site a user of type author is created by default, but for a few users a user is not created. For other users it is working fine but for a few users it is creating the issue.

How can Facebook login functionality when clicking "Add Story" be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

If the use registers via a facebook than the infor are drawn from the facebook. If some of the info required are not there in their facebook account than wordpress denies to create the user.

Comment: Hiii, Can you please let me know what are the required things actually.Public profile and Email address is accessible even though few user are not able to create account and logged in to the system.